# how to use select for update in spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, mariadb, mybatis, select-for-update

I'm using spring-boot v.4.3.18  and mariadb v.10.4.6 now .
I'd like to use select for update like movie reservation service or Bank Transfer service.

my project is connected mariadb like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIx6a.png)

and i'm using mapper for read data.

Is there any method to query 'select for update' using mybatis?

if there is nothing , then please tell me how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Are you using Spring Data JPA Repositories?

Comment: In MyBatis, there is no difference between plain `SELECT` and `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE`. Just write a normal select and append `for update` at the end.